# Django many-to-may : how get row id in related table

Tags: python, sql, django, models

I have 2 simple models for example

```
class First(m.Model):
    target_field = m.CharField()
class Second(m.Model):
    link_field = m.ManyToManyField(First)
```

Related linking table look like this:
id | second_id | first_id

How can i get ID? Not second_id or first_id - exactly row ID.
I cant find Django methods for it, and wrote it my self.
Thanks for help.

UPD.
For frontend API i need cross ID for related objects.

```
q_second = Second.objects.select_related().all()
for i in q_second.link_field.all()
    print i.pk
```

this print ID in First table its ok, but i need row id in related second_link_field table

Comment: Can you show a lil' bit of context, like what have you tried so far and which object you want to use to get the id value.

Answer (score 4):

May be you need this:

```
seconds = Second.objects.all()
for second in seconds:
    for i in Second.link_field.through.objects.filter(link_field=second):
        print i.id
```

`through` object is a usual django model corresponding intermediate table of many-to-many field, you can query it to fetch ids of entries

Comment: It can also be helpful to explain what's happening when you post code, to help the asker understand your solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use `through` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through and overwrite this model manually. So you can get `second_id` or `first_id` just using ORM.

Comment: I know about `through`, and i have no problems with getting data traditional ways, and i **dont need** `second_id` or `first_id`! I need row ID.

Comment: You know about `through` but why don't you want use it?

Comment: I dont need `thougth`. I can get id by custom non Django methods. I ask about existing Django way.