# Django many-to-many :how to get the id

Tags: django, many-to-many

I have models with manytomany field:

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    Company_Group = models.ManyToManyField(Company)

class Company(models.Model):
    Pref_Company_Name_Flg = models.CharField(u'Preferred Name Flag',max_length=255, default="")
    Pref_Company_Name = models.CharField(u'Preferred Name',max_length=255, default="")
```

I want to filter the id of brands in containing "company_instance"

```
brands = Brand.objects.all()
company_instance=company.objects.filter(id =company_id)
for brand in brands:
    for i in Brand.Company_Group.through.objects.filter(Company_Group = brand):
        print i.id
```

I have found the Similar problem as follows: [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20772235/django-many-to-may-how-get-row-id-in-related-table)

but Report errors :

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'Company_Group' into field. Choices are: brand, brand_id, company, company_id, id
```

then I try this way,also Report errors:

```
type object 'Brand' has no attribute 'Company_id'
```

Thanks andvance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just use the reverse relation from `Company` instance like,

```
company = Company.objects.get(id=company_id)
company.brand_set.all() #this would return all Brand instances
                        #with company instance.
```

Comment: with less than 15 Reputation  ,I can only click to the undo acceptance  of this answer ,thanks ~